# Join Multidimension Arrays

Tags: arrays, swift

I have multiple arrays of different sizes, for instance:

```
let array1 = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
let array2 = [[1, 2], [1, 2]]
let array3 = [[1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2]]
```

And I wanna join them together so I get the final array:

```
let finalArray = [[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2], [1, 2]]
```

Any ideia on how can I achieve this goal in a efficient way?

Comment: You could use `zip` and `+`, but the problem is that what you are doing with the extra `[1,2]` is arbitrary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
var finalArray:[[Int]] = []
for index in 0..<max(array1.count,array2.count,array3.count) {
    finalArray.append([])
    if index < array1.count {
        finalArray[index].appendContentsOf(array1[index])
    }
    if index < array2.count {
        finalArray[index].appendContentsOf(array2[index])
    }
    if index < array3.count{
        finalArray[index].appendContentsOf(array3[index])
    }
}
finalArray // [[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2], [1, 2]]
```

Comment: Thanks @Leo, in this situation I prefer the old 'for' in favor of functional operators (map, reduce), also your solution is a bit faster then the others and more (at least for me) readable.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
var arrays = [array1, array2, array3];
var maxSize = Math.max.apply(null, arrays.map(function(a){ return a.length }))
var result = [];

for (var i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++) {
  result[i] = [];
  for (var j = 0; j < maxSize; j++) {
    if (arrays[j][i]) {
      result[i] = result[i].concat(arrays[j][i]);
    }
  }
}
```

This assumes that what you want to do is end up with a result array that has the same number of elements as the largest input array, putting together the elements in the same position in the input arrays into the output array in the same order as the original arrays.

Answer (score 1):

`zip` is the obvious function needed to combine the arrays but it is not able to handle the uneven lengths and the `map` calls may not be as efficient as a C-like algorithm in this case. However as an exercise, here is a more functional approach **IF** the arrays can be preprocessed to include empty arrays for missing data

```
let z12  = zip(array1, array2)
let z123 = zip(z12, array3)
let answer = z123.map { [$0.0.0, $0.0.1, $0.1].flatMap { $0 } }
```

I have changed the arrays from `let` to `var` so that they can be appended and I have changed the data for indices 1 to make the answer more obviously correct.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @price your solution by far looks very elegant but testing it out with larger arrays the perfomance falls down a bit. But very cool approach, I liked it!